# How can I indent all text in a paragraph except the first line?

Tags: html, css

This is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVJK8/).

What I'm trying to do is indent everything after the first line.

Right now it looks like:

```
Categories: Aperiri 
nostrum similique cu 
pro, maiorum delectus 
quo eu. Mentitum
```

I'm trying to get it to look like:

```
Categories: Aperiri 
  nostrum similique cu 
  pro, maiorum delectus 
  quo eu. Mentitum
```

I've tried adding to the css:

```
display: block;
margin: 2px;
```

But this screws up my text wrapping.

How can I have inline display but also indent after the first line in css?

Comment: The quickest way is to just wrap the text you want indented in a `<span>` and style that span.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20510651/2680216

Comment: Did the wrong answer somehow get selected as the best one?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `text-indent` property with a negative value and compensate it with a left margin.

For instance:

```
.negative-indent {
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-indent: -40px;
}
```

Reference for `text-indent` property: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

Comment: Can I do this with display:inline; ?

Comment: I believe the code [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21316564/3227787) solves your issue. The problem is that you were trying to make it work for a combination of two divs while adjusting the CSS of only one of them. :)

Answer (score 13):

Use `:first-line` and `text-indent` tag. Put your whole text in one block (div or paragraph). Indent all lines and then set the first line to `text-indent = 0`

Example:

```
p { text-indent: -10px }
p:first-line { text-indent: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
.hClass p{
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.iClass{
    font-style: oblinque;
    color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gVJK8/5/

Comment: any other solution without padding-left?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The answers published here until now gave me a bad result (letters were overlapping each other) when complex layout (eg tables) was present in the paragraph being undented.

After much trying I found that the following didn't mess with these.

```
text-indent: 0.5em hanging;
```

Only tried it in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome.  Docs say "hiding behind experimental flag" ??? https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-indent

Comment: just tried in slimjet (don't use Chrome at home), still works, Slimjet Version 23.0.5.0 (based on Chromium 74.0.3729.108)

Answer (score -1):

I found it best to use a simple solution like this:

```
p:nth-child(n+2){text-indent: 3px;}
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.