# text align in html/css

Tags: css, text-align

As you can see the text is not properly aligned.

I want the text to be displayed like these and it should be justified also:

```
        Ethics/Moral:Respect for mankind,the environment and  fglll
                     nature without exceptionRespect for mankind,the   
                     environment and   nature without exception
```

The next line should start at the same point as the previous line.
How can I do it in css

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow where we help you with your code.  The less code you share, the less likely we can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316313/how-can-i-indent-all-text-in-a-paragraph-except-the-first-line

Comment: Do you want every indentation to be the same regardless of how long the bolded text are for each? Or should the indentation be dependent on the bolded text's length?

Comment: I updated my answer to better show how I meant you could do. Please let me know if I can do more to help you with a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `flex` you can do like this

*Note, the `br` I added is merely there to show how it behaves when breaking line*

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.row ~ .row {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.row div:first-child {
  color: steelblue
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    Ethics/Moral:
  </div>
  <div>
    Respect for mankind, the environment and<br>nature - without exception 
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    Honesty:
  </div>
  <div>
    Treating everyone with sincerity and<br>integrity 
  </div>  
</div>
```

and if you need 2 even columns and have dynamic content, use `display: table-row/table-cell`

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.row div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.row ~ .row div {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
.row div:first-child {
  color: steelblue
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    Ethics/Moral:
  </div>
  <div>
    Respect for mankind, the environment and<br>nature - without exception 
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    Honesty:
  </div>
  <div>
    Treating everyone with sincerity and<br>integrity 
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

*Side note:*

*As Paulie D very well pointed out, `dl/dt/dd` is likely the most semantically appropriate markup, though my suggested styling might give you the wanted result. Feel free to combine the two*

Answer (score 1):

@MuFFes mentioned the css properties `text-indent`, but I prefer to use dl, dt, and dd elements.

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}
dt:after {
  content: ":";
}
dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 110px;
  padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Ethics/Moral</dt>
  <dd>Respect for mankind, the environment and nature without exception.</dd>
  <dt>Honesty</dt>
  <dd>Treating everyone with sincerity and integrity.</dd>
  <dt>Quality/Safety</dt>
  <dd>Mankind and the environment, the product and its utilization -achieving the optimum together.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: More importantly, this is semantically the best.structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using ::first-line pseudoelement is the best you can do in that case. Try:

```
::first-line {
    text-indent: -40px;
}
```

You have to adjust text-indent by yourself.

It would be also a little bit easier with the sample of your code.